# time_tuple = datetime.timetuple() TypeError: unbound method datetime.timetuple() needs an argument , this is the error i am getting. how to solve?

Tags: python

```
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
def datetotimestamp(date):
    time_tuple = datetime.timetuple()
    timestamp = round(time.mktime(time_tuple))
    return timestamp

start = datetotimestamp(datetime(2022,5,18))
end = datetotimestamp(datetime.today)
url = "https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/techCharts/indianMarket/stock/history?symbol=RELIANCE&resolution=5&from='+str(start)+&to=+str(end)+"
print(url)
```

Comment: Try `time_tuple = datetime.timetuple(date)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The  method `timetuple()` is an instance method, you can't call is on `datetime` class, do like

```
now = datetime.now()
tt = now.timetuple()
timestamp = round(time.mktime(tt))
```

---

For getting the timestamp just use `datetime.timestamp()`

```
now = datetime.now()
print(round(now.timestamp()))
```